# How to set viewmodel property from outisde when a new toast notification comes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I have the following Model in my MVVM Windows Phone project

```
public class ConversationModel
{
    public string FromUserId { get; set; }
    public string FromUserName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeSent { get; set; }


}
```

And I have below property in my ConversationViewModel. The Conversation.xaml uses the following property and binds it to its UI elements and the data is displayed correctly.

```
   private ConversationModel _ConvData;

    public ConversationModel ConvData
    {
        get
        {
            return App.gAllConversations.Where(x => x.FromUserId ==  App.gCurrentUserId).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        set { _ConvData = value;RaisePropertyChanged("ConvData"); }
    }
```

when I call the Conversation.xaml using NavigationService.Navigate() ,it shows the existing chat data with BuddyA by pulling the data from gAllConversations which is an observableCollection of ConversationModel. And while I am in the Conversation.xaml window and if I receive a new toast notification message from the same FromUserId who is BuddyA of current Conversation.xaml,  I just want to update the ObservableCollection Messages property of the ConversationModel by appending this new message to the list of existing messages in the chat /conversation window. This is because property ConvData set method is called first when Conversation.xaml is navigated and later updating the same BuddyA's content in Conversation.xaml.cs OnNavigatedTo method has successfully updated the existing data to UI and later appended the new message also.

When I try to modify the gAllConversations in Conversation.xaml.cs when i receive the new toast notification from BuddyA and if I am already in the BuddyA's window, the UI shows new message from BuddyA if the BuddyA was already there in the gAllConversations earlier. Now while being in the conversation.xaml window for UserA if I receive a new message from UserB (there is no existing chat history with userB in gAllConversation object) I am loading the Conversation.xaml (upon clicking the notification and this time Set property of ConvData will set nothing as there was no data ) and in Conversation.xaml.cs when I try add a new entry to the collection for initiating a new conversation for ConvB I don't see the changes reflecting back in the UI because set property call would have initially set the null data. How do I fix this issue ?

And is there a better way of handling this whole scenario so that I can avoid writing the code in code behind of Conversation.xaml.cs . Please let me know if there is an alternative way of handling this conversations cleanly.

Comment: Are you sure the `Messages` collection isn't being nulled or `new` collection created after you add new entry?

Comment: you could implement Property changed event -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @HappyLee how do I modify this property data from outside which is mostly conversation.xaml.cs ??

Comment: @dellywheel , Yes I would initialize with a new ConversationModel when there is a first time conversation with BuddyB upon  receiving the new notification.But being in the Conversation.xaml.cs when I make this change the entry I add to gAllConvesration object doesn't reflect in the UI.